# Переход в последний подкаталог каталога, используя cmd

Tags: cmd, windows-7, консоль, командная-строка

Возможно ли, используя только команды cmd, перейти в последний подкаталог каталога, не зная его имя? Например структура каталога:

`-----Главный каталог
---Подкаталог 1
---Подкаталог 2`

Как нибудь возможно перейти в "Подкаталог 2", не используя его имя при переходе? Т.е. мне всегда надо попадать в последний подкаталог главной директории.

Comment: Последний - по какому критерию?

Comment: Ну по тому, как папки сами располагаются в системе. Т.е. как они сейчас лежат, так и надо взять. Видимо по алфавиту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /D %%x IN (*.*) DO SET MyFolder="%%x"
CD %MyFolder%
SET MyFolder=
```

Если необходим иной порядок, нежели дефолтный "по алфавиту", вместо шаблона следует использовать вывод команды `DIR` с выводом только каталогов и требуемой сортировкой:

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%x IN ('dir /A:D /B /O:N') do  SET MyFolder="%%x"
CD %MyFolder%
SET MyFolder=
```

Comment: На самом деле, никто не гарантирует порядок при таком обходе, хотя во многих случаях он будет совпадать с алфавитным.

Comment: @Qwertiy *никто не гарантирует порядок при таком обходе* Дело происходит в Windows. Если речь идёт о файловой системе NTFS, имена будут возвращаться в том порядке, в каком они идут в индексе объектов ФС - т.е. в алфавитном. Если же ФС - FATx, то имена возвращаются в порядке их физического расположения в (под)каталоге. Для других ФС (включая сетевые) порядок будет определяться реализацией драйвера доступа к файловой системе.

Comment: В алфавитном с учётом регистра или без? Насколько я помню, я и на ntfs встречал отклонения от алфавитного. А на ext вообще шли в рандомном (из винды). Ну и fat отлично жив на флешках.

Comment: @Qwertiy *В алфавитном с учётом регистра или без?* Определяется кодировкой. Если более строго - не в алфавитном, а в лексикографическом. Для Windows, NTFS и латиницы - регистронезависимо. *я и на ntfs встречал отклонения от алфавитного* Вероятно, следствие наличия визуально схожих символов. *на ext вообще шли в рандомном* Вопросы к драйверу.

Comment: Спасибо, для моих нужд подошло. У меня там всего несколько папок, а название у них - в цифрах. Так что вряд ли здесь будут какие то проблемы=)